# Adding text to a ggplot bar plot by group within a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a dataset like this:

```
XX<-as.factor(c('P','P','P','R','R','R','F','F','F'))
YY<-c(2,3,6,3,5,3,2,3,4)
Facto<-c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
Text<-c("Z","Z","F","Z","H","Z","Z",'Z',"M")
MyData<-data.frame(XX,YY,Facto,Text)
rm(Facto)
```

My goal is to have a function to create a bar chart with text above each bar

```
MyBarPlot<-function(Data, ColName){
  dodger = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
  ggplot(Data, aes(x=XX, y=YY, fill=Facto))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black",position=position_dodge())+
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE,option = "D",name=)+
    geom_text(aes(label=Text, group = ColName), position = dodger, col='red')+
    theme_minimal()
  
  
}
```

When I run the above function, the "fill=" argument works just fine, but the "group by" aspect for geom_text does not.

```
MyBarPlot(MyData,'Facto')
```

If I change the "group=" line in the function like this:

```
MyBarPlot<-function(Data, ColName){
      dodger = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
      ggplot(Data, aes(x=XX, y=YY, fill=Facto))+
        geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black",position=position_dodge())+
        scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE,option = "D",name=)+
        geom_text(aes(label=Text, group = Facto), position = dodger, col='red')+
        theme_minimal()
      
      
    }
```

I get what I want, but I lose the ability to assign this variable within my function. Is there way I can assign the "group=" dynamically within my function call, just as I'm doing with the "fill=" argument?

Comment: It seems like your function is not currently using the `ColName` parameter anywhere.

Comment: [Here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function-1) is a good primer on the nonstandard evaluation aspects of using ggplot2 inside functions. I think one reason your function worked as it did is because you have the variables in you global environment that you likely couldn't expect the user of the function to have.

Comment: Apologies- "fill=Facto" should be fill = "ColName"

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
MyBarPlot<-function(Data, ColName){
  dodger = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
  ggplot(Data, aes(x=XX, y=YY, fill= {{ColName}}))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black",position=position_dodge())+
    viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE,option = "D",name=)+
    geom_text(aes(label=Text), position = dodger, col='red')+
    theme_minimal()
}


MyBarPlot(MyData,Facto)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks- I didn't realize including the "group by" command was what was causing the problem. Just dropping it as you suggest fixed it